# HttpWebResponse stream stops getting data from url

Tags: c#, download, httpwebrequest

I am working on a MultiThreadedDownloader. The program downloads the content using different partial contents.

With a low speed connection, some of these partial request stops getting data suddenly sometimes and they don't make progress even all parts are downloaded. I can't understand the reason of this problem.

> My code to get response

```
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
            | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
            | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
            | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;

        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        req.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 100;
        req.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = true;
        req.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        req.KeepAlive = false;
        req.Timeout = 5000;
        req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

        HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        Stream tempStream = resp.GetResponseStream();

        while ((bytesRead = tempStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            file.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
        }
        file.Close();
        resp.Close();
        tempStream.Close();
        req.Abort();
```

The response doesn't throw exception. After the download got a little progress,  the partial download stops getting progress. Some of them is downloaded successfully, some of them is not.

> Problem image

[image]

As you see, the download progress is almost done. But it can't be 100% because of the download issue. The white parts on the progressbar below are the what i am talking about.

What may be the reason for this problem?

**UPDATE**

I have figured out the problem is simply the low connection speed. There is more than one connection to download at the same time and this makes the connection speed lower for each partial downloads.

`HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream` method can't get enough bytes from the source and waits at that code line. Sometimes `Stream.Read` throws `UnexpectedEndOfStream` error and sometimes `bytesRead` returns *0* even if it is not supposed to be.

So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Well I don't see anywhere that you're disposing of either the `HttpWebResponse` or the `Stream` you get from it, both of which *should* be disposed using a `using` statement. (I'd also strongly recommend using a cast instead of `as` here...)

Comment: Actually, I am disposing the Response and aborting the Requests when the download finished. I didn't put that code part because I wanted to keep the question short. But it will be better I put that part.

Comment: It would be ideal if you'd provide a [mcve].

Comment: Where is the code which calls this? Is that where you are doing the multithreading work? The problem could be there.